# Is it possible to append rows to an existing Arrow (PyArrow) Table?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am aware that "Many Arrow objects are immutable: once constructed, their logical properties cannot change anymore" ([docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/conventions.html#immutability)). In [this blog post by one of the Arrow creators](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/) it's said

> Table columns in Arrow C++ can be chunked, so that appending to a table is a zero copy operation, requiring no non-trivial computation or memory allocation.

However, I am unable to find in the documentation how to append a row to a table. `pyarrow.concat_tables(tables, promote=False)` does something similar, but it is my understanding that it produces a new Table object, rather than, say, adding chunks to the existing one.

I am unsure if this is operation is at all possible/makes sense (in which case I'd like to know how) or if it doesn't (in which case, `pyarrow.concat_tables` is exactly what I need).

Similar questions:

- [In PyArrow, how to append rows of a table to a memory mapped file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66596063/554319) asks specifically about memory-mapped files. I am asking generally about any `Table` object. Could be coming from a `read_csv` operation or be manually constructed.
- [Using pyarrow how do you append to parquet file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47113813/554319) talks about Parquet files. See above.
- [Pyarrow Write/Append Columns Arrow File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71256850/554319) talks about columns, but I'm talking about rows.
- https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/3622 asks this same question, but it doesn't have a satisfying answer (in my opinion).

Comment: This should probably be explained more clearly somewhere but effectively Table is a container of pointers to actual data. So you can concatenate two tables, and you'll just be copying the pointers, not the data itself. Hence ["If promote==False, a zero-copy concatenation will be performed."](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.concat_tables.html?highlight=concat_tables#pyarrow.concat_tables)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, a Table in PyArrow/Arrow C++ isn't really the data itself, but rather a container consisting of pointers to data. How it works is:

- A Buffer represents an actual, singular allocation. In other words, Buffers are contiguous, full stop. They may be mutable or immutable.
- An Array contains 0+ Buffers and imposes some sort of semantics into them. (For instance, an array of integers, or an array of strings.) Arrays are "contiguous" in the sense that each buffer is contiguous, and conceptually the "column" is not "split" across multiple buffers. (This gets really fuzzy with nested arrays: a struct array does split its data across multiple buffers, in some sense! I need to come up with a better wording of this, and will contribute this to upstream docs. But I hope what I mean here is reasonably clear.)
- A ChunkedArray contains 0+ Arrays. A ChunkedArray is not logically contiguous. It's kinda like a linked list of chunks of data. Two ChunkedArrays can be concatenated "zero copy", i.e. the *underlying buffers* will not get copied.
- A Table contains 0+ ChunkedArrays. A Table is a 2D data structure (both columns and rows).
- A RecordBatch contains 0+ Arrays. A RecordBatch is also a 2D data structure.

Hence, you can concantenate two Tables "zero copy" with `pyarrow.concat_tables`, by just copying pointers. But you cannot concatenate two RecordBatches "zero copy", because you have to concatenate the Arrays, and then you have to copy data out of buffers.

Comment: Superb explanation! Thanks for spelling out the relationship between `Table -> ChunkedArray -> Array` and `RecordBatch -> Array`. The [Python docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html) mention all the arrays separately but then `ChunkedArrays` are introduced suddenly when talking about tables, perhaps a better categorization could be done there.

Comment: You wrote that _"conceptually the "column" is not "split" across multiple buffers"_ in some sense, but not in another. Would it be correct to say that there is a bijection between elements of the Array and elements of _each_ of the 0+ Buffers? PyArrow documentation is unclear about the relation between an Array and Buffers. It may seem that "Array can hold multiple Buffers" contradicts "Array is contiguous". I guess, there is no contradiction because Buffers represent _different aspects_ of the Array, e.g. one Buffer stores int values, another Buffer stores NaN bitmap. Is this correct?

Comment: Is there any resource that says why arrow arrays are immutable? Say compared to numpy arrays, there would be no problem modifying values directly there.

Comment: Some Arrow implementations allow mutable arrays (e.g. Java), but the C++ one that underlies PyArrow does not. Mutable arrays have their own pitfalls, which Pandas and Arrow-Java users have to deal with.

Comment: @paperskilltrees sorry for the delay, but I think that's correct. Well, with a caveat; StringView arrays can have multiple data buffers. So you could almost zero-copy concatenate two StringView arrays, unlike other arrays, but you'd still have to copy their validity and offset buffers.

Comment: And consequently there isn't a bijection anymore, elements in a StringView array will "appear" once in the validity and offset buffers, but will appear in at most 1 of the data buffers.